# Google Menu Script to Count Responses taken from linked google form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I made a Google spreadsheet that is linked to a Google form that I am collecting responses from. Each column in the spreadsheet has a question from the form, but I am only trying to get a count of how many times a given name comes up in the second column.

I made a custom menu that is meant to bring up a dialog box to confirm how many times a certain name has come up, by answering yes or no to the amount.

```js
function summarizeNames() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('Is this amount of Jacks correct?', 12 , ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  var response = ui.prompt('Is this amount of Roses correct?', 6 , ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  var response = ui.prompt('Is this amount of Bills correct?', 3 , ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
}
```

I want the number of times it appears as a value in the dialog box after the question. I found a function with a for loop to try and count said times but I'm having trouble taking that value and having it appear on the dialog box.

```js
function getData(target) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var lrow = ss.getLastRow();
  var r = ss.getRange(2, 2, lrow-1, 1); // lrow-1 to not count header
  var data = r.getValues();
  var count = 0; // 0 must be declared here or you'll get error: Overflow on the spreadsheet

  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] == target) { // can repeat this part depending how many values you want to search for
      count++;
    }
  }
  return (count);
}
```

Is there any way to do that and store the values for other names too?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function summarizeNames() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  p('Jack');
  p('Rose');
  p('Bill');

  function p(target) {
    var count = getData(target);
    var response = ui.prompt(`Is this amount of ${target}s correct?`, count , ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
    return response;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @idfurw. Is there any way to loop the prompts so that each name's count is confirmed seperately?

Comment: Both your code and my code are confirming separately. What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I should have phrased that better. I'm just learning app script so it's a little difficult at the moment, the code worked great. But can it be done so that each name has its own prompt to confirm the amount that corresponds to its given count?

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. I still cannot get what you mean. Three individual but consecutive dialogs are now coming up. So I think it is now 'each name has its own prompt'.

Comment: @KristopherPacifico Hi, there was a typo in the provided code (`{` missing in `${target}`). I hope that will solve the issue for you. If that's not it, please consider providing more details about your desired outcome.

Comment: Sorry for my typo and thank you for the correction @Iamblichus